# Удалить все пустые значение в excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Читаю файл по строкам и столбцам:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('Пример выгрузки из 1С.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('example')
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
print(data)


from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Пример выгрузки из 1С.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['example']
print('Столбец A:')
print('**********')
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    print(row[0].value)
print('**********')
print('Столбец B:')
print('**********')
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    print(row[1].value)
print('**********')
print('Столбец C:')
print('**********')
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    print(row[2].value)
print('**********')
print('Столбец D:')
print('**********')
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    print(row[3].value)
print('**********')
```

Получается:

```
Столбец A:
**********
Акты выполненных работ
None
Дата

Всего
None
None
**********
Столбец B:
**********
None
None
Сумма

None
None
None
**********
Столбец C:
**********
None
None

None
None
None
None
None
**********
Столбец D:
**********
None
None
Договор

None
None
None
None
None
None
**********
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить все ' ' и None. Заранее благодарна за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

In [37]: df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\temp\a.xlsx', skiprows=3)

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
                  Дата    Сумма                Контрагент                                   Договор
0  25.07.2018 11:18:07   295000  УРАЛЬСКИЕ ЛОКОМОТИВЫ ООО  Договор ТПП-799-610/286-18 от 08.05.2018
1   01.08.2018 0:00:00   920671   ПИИ ТЮМЕНЬДОРПРОЕКТ ОАО             Договор ТПП-798 от 05.04.2018
2  09.08.2018 14:44:12   401200  УРАЛЬСКИЕ ЛОКОМОТИВЫ ООО  Договор ТПП-799-610/286-18 от 08.05.2018
3  21.08.2018 23:59:59   188800            АО "Транспорт"             Договор ТПП-790 от 01.06.2017
4  21.08.2018 23:59:59   354000       ООО "Ямал-Логистик"             Договор ТПП-800 от 05.07.2018
5  17.09.2018 23:59:59  1613985   ПИИ ТЮМЕНЬДОРПРОЕКТ ОАО             Договор ТПП-798 от 05.04.2018
6                Всего  3773656                       NaN                                       NaN

In [39]: df['Дата'].tolist()
Out[39]:
['25.07.2018 11:18:07',
 '01.08.2018 0:00:00',
 '09.08.2018 14:44:12',
 '21.08.2018 23:59:59',
 '21.08.2018 23:59:59',
 '17.09.2018 23:59:59',
 'Всего']

In [40]: df.loc[:5, 'Сумма']
Out[40]:
0     295000
1     920671
2     401200
3     188800
4     354000
5    1613985
Name: Сумма, dtype: int64
```

---

по умолчанию Pandas обрезает строки и столбцы таким образом, чтобы DataFrame влез на экран. Чтобы посмотреть все настройки отображения наберите в Python IDE (iPython, Jupyter, etc.) `pd.options.display.` и нажмите `Tab` чтобы увидеть все доступные атрибуты:

```
In [41]: pd.options.display.
                          pd.o…y.chop_threshold         pd.o…y.date_yearfirst         pd.options.display.html       pd.o…y.max_columns
                          pd.o…y.colheader_justify      pd.options.display.encoding   pd.options.display.large_repr pd.o…y.max_colwidth
                          pd.o…y.column_space           pd.o…y.expand_frame_repr      pd.options.display.latex      pd.o…y.max_info_columns       >
                          pd.o…y.date_dayfirst          pd.o…y.float_format           pd.o…y.max_categories         pd.o…y.max_info_rows

In [41]: pd.options.display.max_
                                 pd.o…y.max_categories       pd.o…y.max_info_columns     pd.o…y.max_seq_items
                                 pd.o…y.max_columns          pd.o…y.max_info_rows
                                 pd.o…y.max_colwidth         pd.options.display.max_rows
```

изменить атрибут можно так:

```
pd.options.display.max_columns = 12
```

или так:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 12)
```

[Документация о настройках и опциях Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня в файле несколько листов. Как pandas указать на прочтение конкретного листа?

Comment: @Ireen1985, используйте параметр sheet_name=“Sheet2”

Comment: спасибо. Мне помогло. У меня ещё один вопрос. Работаю в PyCharm. И когда загружаю таблицу с помощью pandas, всё содержимое таблицы не отражается. Показывается первый и последний столбец, а между ними многоточие. Может быть, Вы знаете как развернуть полностью таблицу в PyCharm?

Comment: @Ireen1985, дополнил ответ...

Comment: супер!!! Огромное Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

В каждом цикле просто добавьте еще строчку проверки `if`:

```
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    if row[0].value:
        print(row[0].value)
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    if row[1].value:
        print(row[1].value)
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    if row[2].value:
        print(row[2].value)
for row in sheet_ranges.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
    if row[3].value:
        print(row[3].value)
```

Comment: супер!!! Все сработало. Спасибо большое. А что делать с чтением строк? Там тоже пустые значения

Comment: @Ireen1985 Я не совсем поял вопрос. В смысле что делать с чтением строк? Если в файле есть пустые строки, то вы и их читать будете.

Comment: я уже разделалась с этой проблемой. Спасибо Вам еще раз